# Pandas filtering/pooling and keeping the old Indices

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, indexing

Here is my question:

I have 2 columns in the same data. One column for ID (several Id's are repeated) and the Other column is about age (many ages are repeated).
I want to create new columns in which I regroup the Ids then call/display their indices where they where in the OLD table.
An example:
age = [12, 14, 10, 12, 10] ( the indices are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
what I wish is to obtain the following:
Age2 = [10, 10, 12, 12, 14] , Indexe = [3, 5, 1, 4, 2]
When I call age 10 I can obtain that 10 is originally in the following indices (3, 5).

My code sample:

```
    for ind in ind_list:
        data.temp = data[data['age'] == ind].copy()
        inds = data.temp.index.tolist()
     #Here I obtain a list that inform me about the indexes of the IDS in 
     the old data
```

an other method much more longer:

```
        Final = []
        index = 0;
        for i in range(len(CTs2) - 1, -1, -1):
        data.temp = data['student_ID'][inds]
        data.temp = data.temp[data.temp == CTs2[i]]
        inds2 = data.temp.index.tolist()

     if len(inds2) > 0:
            CTs2.pop(i)
            final.extend(inds2)
            final.extend(inds2)
            special_index += 1
```

I hope some help ... Thank you all

Comment: Can create a sample input table and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a column that stores the indices of repeated ages, you can use

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,(10,2)),columns=['ID','Age'])

frame['Age2'] = [[dex for y,dex in zip(frame.Age,frame.index) if x == y] for x in frame.Age]
```